# RxJs observable: transforming data into enum causes a type error

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an `Angular 14` app and I'm using Angular's `HttpClient` to make a request to my backend.

However, I have a requirement to transform the incoming data from a value returned from the server to an enum value that is defined in my frontend.

To do this, I've wrote this code:

```
public getState(): Observable<AuthState> {
    return this.http.get<any>(apiPaths.auth.isAuthorized, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
        map(resp => {
            if (resp.ok) {
                if (this.responseIsValid(resp.body)) {
                    return AuthState.Ok;
                } else {
                    return AuthState.NotAuthorized;
                }
            } else {
                return AuthState.NotAuthenticated;
            }
        })
    );
}
```

As you can see, I'm getting a value from the backend and mapping it to a value of the `AuthState` enum, which is defined as follows:

```
export enum AuthState {
    NotAuthenticated = 'NotAuthenticated',
    NotAuthorized = 'NotAuthorized',
    Ok = 'Ok',
    ConnectionError = 'ConnectionError'
}
```

This seems to work, but here comes the problem: I also need to catch errors, so I added the `catchError` opertator into the observable pipe, like this:

```
public getState(): Observable<AuthState> {
    return this.http.get<any>(apiPaths.auth.isAuthorized, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
        map(resp => {
            if (resp.ok) {
                if (this.responseIsValid(resp.body)) {
                    return AuthState.Ok;
                } else {
                    return AuthState.NotAuthorized;
                }
            } else {
                return AuthState.NotAuthenticated;
            }
        }),
        catchError(err => {
            return AuthState.ConnectionError;
        })
    );
}
```

As soon as I do this, hoever, the code stops compiling. The compiler throws the following error:

> Type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AuthState>'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AuthState'

It's like adding the `catchError` operator makes the entire pipe return `Observable<string>` instead of `Obsevable<AuthState>`.

Why is this happening?
Note that this only happens when using an enum, if I change it to use any other type it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return observable, so change the catchError block to:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

catchError(err => {
   return of(AuthState.ConnectionError);
})
```

Comment: Nope, tried already, if I do it the error changes to `Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AuthState>'`

Comment: Check where you imported `of` from, or some other code is not correct, I just copied your coded and tested, and I don't see any compilation error

Comment: You are right! My IDE had imported some other `of` function from some other random node module in my solution... dumb mistake.